# Mysql - how to random select 1 row in a large repetitive set such that each row had an `equal` chance of selection

Tags: mysql, random, unique

I im trying to figure out a simple thing:

how to `random select` 1 row in a large `repetitive` set such that each row had an `equal` chance of selection?

For example, a table of products with each product having multiple entries, I just want to select 1 random. But the `'chance'` of that one should not be more than others due to its repetition.

One solution is to get unique list (with `GROUP BY`) and get `RANDOM` from this subquery. But for a large dataset, thats not an optimal solution, whcihc is what I need help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take the number of rows as the basis for the random number and then use this as the basis of a limit range that selects just that 1 row.

e.g. `LIMIT X,1` where x is the random number.

Comment: So I count the number of unique rows, then take limits with that. how will take make selected result having equal chance of being selected?

Comment: You feed the number of rows into a random number generator. It is the random number so obtained that you use for X.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple first you have to know. numuber of row in ur table. (store in `$cnt_row`) with satisfied that condition. 
then use `randome();` function to get random number and pass that count row as parameter. like this.

```
$row= random($cont_row);
```

add ur random number to query at the end like this

```
limit --$row,1
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: which language is this with `random()` function in your example?

Comment: So I count the number of unique rows, then take limits with that? how will take make selected result having equal chance of being selected?

Comment: I userd php language.. random functions means if u pass value as 5 then it will return varible between 1 to 5 only okay.  random(5) its output will be 1,2,3,4,5 any one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
1) Select Distinct records from your table and create a view

```
CREATE VIEW My_View AS SELECT DISTINCT (Col_Name) FROM Table_Name
```

2) and then randomly select row from that view

`SELECT * FROM`My_View`ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`

Hope it will help :)

Comment: looks good in simple concept, but I have so many dynamic where parameters added on run time based on filters. So it becomes impossible then.

Comment: i am not aware of your scenario but you can always include as many columns as you want in your view at the time of view creation and can add as many where conditions as you want to achieve your goal